# Angular $http not showing all headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, header, response

I have an issue where the $http object does not return all the headers. I have done my research and saw that by default the object returned will only show a limited list of header data unless you specify 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. I have done so below but still do not get a full list of header data. Any suggestions?

```
this.$http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'Etag';
this.$http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
this.$http.get('http://123.456.78.900:3000/api/events?' + filter)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log('data', response.data);
    console.log('headers', response.headers());
});
```

Response:

```
headers Object {content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The promise function has 4 parameters, of which the third one is headers. Try using those.

```
this.$http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'Etag';
this.$http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
this.$http.get('http://123.456.78.900:3000/api/events?' + filter)
.then(function (response, status, headers) {
    console.log('data', response.data);
    console.log('headers', headers);
});
```

Comment: Are you aware that  as of v 1.5 those 4 parameters are now contained in response? I found this info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Oh my bad, i haven't used 1.5